# SharePoint List: Gallery-view photos not showing

Tags: list, list-view, image-display, web-part-gallery

I have a list with about 250 rows and a column called "Photo" that has relatively low-res .jpg images.
It works pretty well in list mode, but then I switch to the Gallery view everything breaks apart. Only rows that DON'T have images have their cards show up. Like this:

[image: galleryview]

I even tried creating a new view and have it be gallery by default. Same result:

[image: view]

I should point out that the pictures were added to the list via `Set-PnPListItem` PnP.Powershell module cmdlet. I don't know if that could have any impact on this or if it's just SharePoint not being able to handle 250 thumbnails in a gallery. It works perfect in List and Compact List formats.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any custom JSON code applied to Gallery view?

Comment: Nothing that I did myself. The current json was generated automatically when switching to gallery view

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it. Somehow the custom-generated json had an issue in the img src:
[image]

After deleting the highlighted area and leaving only "[$Photo.serverRelativeUrl]" it worked! I don't know why it would be appending the serverUrl to the src, but that was the issue.

Comment: Great, glad you managed to solve the issue!